# How to add auto increment number on my new column VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My Datagridview contains data's from my database and I Added new column but i want to insert auto increment number in this column how to do it.

Here's my code for my newly added column

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim idcolumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    With idcolumn
        .HeaderText = "ID"
        .Name = "ID"

    End With

     Dim count as Integer  ="1"
    count = Val(count) +1
    With DataGridView1
        .Columns.Add(idcolumn)
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: This is not directly what you've asked, but I personally find adding autoincrement to the table in DB level more robust. If you have the right to manipulate the table, consider autoincrementing ID as mentioned here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Of course having a calculated autoincrement column in your code is really a bad idea if your app is used by more than one user on the same database.

Comment: as mentioned above, the correct way is to make your field an auto-increment field in the database and let mySQL do the hard work for you. Doing it in the application is not robust - you could easily have a situation where, if you have 2 users (or even just two running copies of the application), then both copies of the app try to issue the same ID at the same time, and then you have a problem with duplicates. Centralise this function in the database with an auto-increment field - it's what it's designed for. Any introductory database tutorial would normally explain this kind of thing.

Comment: may data already have an autoincrement in my table but i just want to autoincrement it in application with the new column ID that i added.

Comment: i just want to generate custom ID in the application.

Comment: if you already have an auto-increment field in your database, why do you need another one in your application? It doesn't really make sense. What is the purpose of it? Why not just use the value from the database, instead of inventing another one?

Comment: i'm just displaying specific data in datagridview, actually the actual value in database is already in 20k records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than add an unbound column to your `DataGridView`, add an extra `DataColumn` to your `DataTable`.  That can be set to auto-increment, e.g.

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable

Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    adapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open()

    'Get the schema from the database without the data.
    adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source)

    'Add an auto-incrementing column to the table.
    With table.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        .AutoIncrementSeed = 1
        .AutoIncrementStep = 1
        .AutoIncrement = True
    End With

    'Get the data.
    adapter.Fill(table)
End Using
```

Now you have the column ready to go when you bind and you don't need any extra code to generate the values.